# adobe flex extreme components

Tags: apache-flex

In my project, we are using Adobe flex extreme components to show grids. i see the grid as below in my jsp( with filters)

```
    <ec:table items="searchResults"
    var="searchResults" 
    imagePath="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/images/table/*.gif"
    view="buttonsOnBottom"
    retrieveRowsCallback="limit"
    filterRowsCallback="limit"
    sortRowsCallback="limit"
    ...    >
 ..
```

what is the function of these three: retrieveRowsCallback,filterRowsCallback,sortRowsCallback.
 What I want is this:
 When the grid loads, show a prefiltered list(e.g. only records with status = 'Active'). The server side can easily return the filtered list, but on the grid , the filter value is shown as 'blank' instead of 'Active'.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Adobe flex extreme components" doesn't exist, or so says google.  This is a 3rd party library and not standard Flex component. You should look up the 3rd party documentation to see what those do.